# Upgrade Eclipse from Java Dev to Java EE dev

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse for Java Developers installed, and I installed the Java EE JDK to start working on Java EE.

How can I upgrade my Eclipse For Java Developers to Eclipse For Java EE Developers?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some way using the update stuff, but I would just download the right version of Eclipse for what you want and start with that. It's easy and fast.

Comment: Okay sorry I don't know how to use stackoverflow yet :p